# limit computation (dominated convergence theorem), finding the dominating function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

How does one find the dominating function $g\in L^{1}$ s.t $|f_{n}|\le g, \forall n$ where all $f_{n}=(1+\frac{x}{n})^{n}e^{-2x}\in L^{1}$

Is it just enough to compute the limit of the sequence? :

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^{n}e^{-2x}=e^{-x}$.

All the functions in the sequence above converge pointwise to $f(x)=e^{-x}$

Is this a sufficient argument to assume that this is my dominating function?

The most common method I have seen was to do ''estimation'' something like that

$|f_{n}|\le|something|\le g$$

Answer (score 0):

> All the functions in the sequence above converge pointwise to $f(x)=e^{-x}$
>
> Is this a sufficient argument to assume that this is my dominating function?

No, it's not sufficient (for example if we would have $f_n=\chi_{(n,n+1)}$.

But we can prove that $|f_n(x)|\leqslant e^{-x}$. To see that , notice that for $x\geqslant 0$,
$$n\log\left(1+\frac xn\right)\leqslant x.$$

Comment: okay, how do we find such dominating function? What is the ''recipe''

Comment: We have to bound what depends on $n$, namely, $\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$. We know that it converges to $e^x$, so an upper bound should involve the exponential function. Now we use an elementary inequality for logarithm.

Comment: so we could use the above inequality to bound the function above i.e $|f_{n}|\le nlog(1+\frac{x}{n})\le x$? I am wondering for which x would that work. The second one as you stated for $x\le 0$ but the first inequality?

Comment: No, we have $\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\leqslant e^x$ hence $|f_n(x)|\leqslant e^{-x}$.